# gmail java api sending with attachment takes ages

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

Google seems to send devs here for help with the gmail api, so please excuse my first post.

I am connecting and sending an email using the java gmail api with an attachment.  The problem I am having is it seems to take up to 10 minutes to actually execute the ....send("me", message).execute() method.

I have tried enabling gzip compression by setting the necessary header values which seems to have helped, but it is still unacceptably slow for what is basically just a small file upload which should complete in a few seconds.

So, my questions to the experts here are:

1) Is anyone else experiencing this slow performance with attachments?
2) Is there a better way to do this perhaps using the upload features?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: Some code would be helpful...


Are there any JARS which interfere with the sending, whom you suspect? (if using Maven - there is a plugin for finding unnecessary jars - 'mvn dependency:analyze'. If not using - highly suggested to do so!)

Comment: Certainly shouldn't take 10 minutes.  It should only take a second or two.

Answer (score 0):

If the attachments are a certain size the gmail api won't accept the large base64 json payload. Depending on the http client you use you might even get a exceptions like "Error writing to server". The upload seems the way to go for attachments larger than 1mb.